# How to solve error : [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <delete-account-modal>?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

My view is like this :

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('title', 'Bank | Myapp')

@section('content')

    @if (Auth::user())
        ...

        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;" @click="modalShow('modal-delete-account',{{ $account['id'] }})">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp;Hapus
            </a>
        </li>
        ...                                 

    @endif

@endsection

@section('modal')
    @include('components.modal.profile.setting.account')
    <delete-account-modal id="modal-delete-account" :id-account="idModal"></delete-account-modal>
@endsection
```

When executed, there exist error on console like this :

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <delete-account-modal> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.  (found in root instance)
```

How can I I solve the error?

Comment: Vue is looking for a component called `delete-account-modal`, so have you registered the `delete-account-modal` component?

Comment: @craig_h, How to register? This is the first time I used vue.js

Comment: It depends, are you compiling everything with `elixir` and creating `.vue` files?

Comment: @craig_h, Yes, I had register on resources\assets\js\app.js. And I add the modal on resources\assets\js\components\bootstrap and resources\assets\js\api. But it's not working

Comment: You might need to show us your app.js

Comment: Please provide a MCVE: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this entirely depends on how you are writing your component. Because Laravel encourages the use of [single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) I'll assume that `delete-account-model` is in a file called `delete-account-model.vue` in `resources/assets/js/components`, I'll also assume that`elixir` is set up to correctly compile `.vue` files

So, in order to register a component globally you can simply add the following to `resources/assets/js/app.js`:

```
Vue.component('delete-account-modal', require('./components/delete-account-model.vue'));
```

Then run `gulp` to re-compile everything. You should then find that the `delete-account-modal` component is available.